# in Drupal, how to make login state consistent between browser pages and embedded XMLRPC client?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, xml-rpc

I have a Drupal site with user logins.  Embedded within this site is a Flash application that shows some data to everybody but allows extra functionality if the user is logged on.  From within Flash, I'm using XMLRPC to access the system.check method (to determine whether the user is logged in) and the user.login method (to log in a user from within Flash).

Within Flash, everything works fine.  However the Flash login state does not seem to correspond to the rest of the site.  For example, if I invoke user.login via XMLRPC, subsequent calls to system.check show that I am logged in, but the Drupal user page still says I'm logged out.  Or if I am logged in both places and then I log out via the Drupal user page, the next call to system.check still indicates that I am logged in.

How can I make the login state consistent between the Drupal GUI and my embedded Flash app?

(Note: I am not using any XMLRPC library, I am just constructing the requisite XML manually and sending POST methods using a URLRequest object.)

EDIT:  I have confirmed via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467449/when-posting-a-form-with-urlrequest-how-to-include-cookies-from-browser-session) and also via testing with a Web Proxy that the SESS cookie returned by the user login page is being picked up and sent back by the flash application.

EDIT: And now I have shown experimentally that even though Flash (via Safari) is sending the same cookie, it gets back a DIFFERENT cookie when it connects to the XMLRPC service than when it requests and HTML page.  In other words, Drupal just doesn't support this kind of synchronization and I'm stuck.  I'm accepting the answer below that put me on the right track.

EDIT: AMHPHP is not fully released for Drupal6 as of this writing, but it turned out to be installed on the site anyway.  Using the [DrupalSite](http://thirdavedesign.com/drupalsite/) library, I was very easily able to log into and out of the site from flash, and the login remained consistent between flash and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not terribly familar with Flash, but do the URLRequest objects "inherit" state from the browser session, including the user login cookies? If not, you'll need to explicitly send the login cookie with your hand-built request or Drupal will think that it's just coming from another web browser at the same IP address.

If you're not quite sure, using the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) plugin might be useful. It lets you inspect any requests that are being piped through the browser, examine their headers, and look at the raw HTTP response object that comes back.

*Update: Even more important than the flash widget getting a session cookie is the flash widget getting the SAME session cookie as the web browser itself. Drupal allows users to log in from multiple machines simultaneously, so if the browser is creating one session and the flash widget is creating another, you'd see the behavior you're describing...*

Comment: I've confirmed that when the flash widget requests an HTML page from the site it gets back the normal cookie, but when it connects to the XML-RPC service, it gets back a different one.  The widget SENDS the html cookie in both cases.  It appears that Drupal treats these as totally separate sessions.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done.

(For details, please see my final edit to the original question and the equivalent information in my comment to @Eaton.)

Comment: Thanks for sussing this out, and sorry it turned into a roadblock. I'm chatting with the maintainer of the BlogAPI module to see if we can classify this as a defect and get it fixed in the next point release...